# How to move footnote marks downward?

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

[image]

In the picture above, I want to move the footnote marks downward.

How should I do?

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[adobefonts]{ctex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[perpage,bottom,hang]{footmisc}

% Solve the conflicts bewteen ctex and footmisc with option `hang`
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\CTEXsetfont{%
\begingroup
\settowidth\ccwd{\CTEX@spaceChar\CJKglue}%
\edef\x{\noexpand\ccwd\the\ccwd}%
\expandafter\endgroup\x
\ifdim\parindent=0pt\else\parindent2\ccwd\fi}
\makeatother

\setlength{\footnotemargin}{1em}

\renewcommand\thefootnote{\ding{\numexpr171+\value{footnote}}}
\renewcommand\footnotesep{1.5em}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello, Section}
Hello, World! Hello, World \footnote{This is a footnote!}! Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

Comment: the style of footnote marks is often set by the document class, so we need to know at least what that class is.  even better would be a small compilable example to test with.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, the MWE is appended.

Comment: it appears that this sample uses the "default" definition of the footnote mark, which calls `\textsuperscript` for both the reference and for the footnote itself.  (the definition is `\def\@makefnmark{...}` in `latex.ltx`.)  a redefinition will have to split the two uses, since i'm sure the reference in text shouldn't be moved down.  this will take some time, so if someone else has a quick answer, please go for it.

Comment: Do you want a *normal* number instead of a superscript number, or do you want to move the whole footnote stuff to the bottom of the page?

Comment: @Johannes_B, I just want to move the marks only, and keep the texts at the original positions.